# Is there a cutomizable linkedin weblink to post on a company page?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I know there is an API to post on a company linkedin page, and a customizable weblink to post on your personal profile (for example: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brighterinvestment.com%2F&title=Brighter%20Investment&summary=This%20new%20fund%20opens%20up%20education%20to%20the%20poor%20and%20shares%20the%20financial%20gains%20with%20its%20investors&source=Brighter%20Investment)

Is there a similar customizable weblink that brings you to a pre-populated page to post on your company page?

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no URL-based equivalent of the share service for posting to your company page.

You would have to do so via an API call or manually on linkedin.com